# Is there a function that makes an image not clickable so that the default chrome widget doesn't appear and allow them to download the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, alt

Is there a function that makes an image not clickable so that the default chrome widget doesn't appear and allow them to download the image??

Comment: Why? They can do it from developer tools.

Comment: You know that if the image is showing, it has already been downloaded to the browser's cache, don't you?

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't know.  excuse

Comment: There is a way to do it with the HTML canvas. look at my answer for the code

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```css
body {
-webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
-moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
-ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

JS

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
</script>
```

HTML

```html
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```